# Can't send data with GET method but with POST

Tags: php, rest, post, get, slim

I'm building the Rest API in Php Slim. API working fine on localhost. Now I placed it on live server. The issue is when I send data in body using `GET` method, Postman shows error: `500 Internal Server Error.`
. But it's working fine when changing `GET` to `POST`. I'm new in backend so don't understand what the issue is. The `index.php` file of API is located in subdirectory as `example.com/api/public/index.php` so I made some changes in `.htaccess` but it's not working.

```
.htaccess

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php73” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php73 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
SetEnvIf Authorization .+ HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$0
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
RewriteRule .* - [env=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /api/public/index.php [L,QSA]


# Don't listing directory
Options -Indexes
ErrorDocument 403 http://www.example.com/
# Follow symbolic links
Options +FollowSymLinks

# Default handler
DirectoryIndex index.php

# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Could I use `POST` instead of `GET` or there is something wrong?

Comment: Have you checked your server's error logs to see what the error is?

Comment: It's in the name. Get is only used to retrieve data. Post send data and reads the response.

Comment: Never send data in get method. Always use `Post` method to send it.

Comment: @El_Vanja I can't see any error in error_log file.

Comment: @Bijan Yes I'm retrieving data based on query i.e SELECT * from books where id =?.

Comment: The public/ directory must be the DocumentRoot of your webserver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The issue is when I send data in body using GET method

Take a look at the [specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.1):

> A payload within a GET request message has no defined semantics;
> sending a payload body on a GET request might cause some existing
> implementations to reject the request.

While it is possible to get *some* clients (e.g. Postman) to make an HTTP GET request with a body and it is possible to get *some* servers to read the body from an HTTP GET request, it does completely lock out some other clients (e.g. the browser APIs of XMLHttpRequest and fetch).

Either don't use a GET request or don't use a request body for this.

Comment: Got it @Quentin. Now sending data in parameters rather than body and it working fine.